# How to do Order by in SSAS

Tags: ssas

As you can see the image, how to make the order like
'<10days'
'10-20 days',
'21-30 days',
'31-50 days'
'>50 days'

is it possible?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUC2D.png

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the image is what you want to achieve but you dont know how to do it in MDX? If so, you could try something like:

```
select Measures.TotalPatient ON COLUMNS,ORDER([YourDimension].[YourHierarchy].[DAYS CATEGORY],Measures.TotalPatient,BASC) ON ROWS FROM YourCube
```

The BASC is order ascending but ignoring the ordering of the hierachy.